# trim() not catching AJAX posted data value of &nbsp;

Tags: php, jquery, unicode, trim

I have a `contenteditable` element, that `onblur` posts it's value to server.

Because it's a `contenteditable`, upon repeated space entries, instead of blank space, it adds `&nbsp;` instead, so the resulting HTML can be:

```
Testing title &nbsp; middle &nbsp; entry &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

That when retrieved with `.text()` from element, looks like normally spaced (underlines mark spaces):

```
Testing_title___middle___entry____
```

This `.text()` value I am posting over to my PHP backend. There I go through the saving procedure. Because I need the string trimmed, a basic `trim($title)` didn't cut it.

And, I cannot seem to get my head around it.

I have tried also this [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha), didn't help either.

Chrome Network inspector, shows it sends over this encoded data:

```
Testing+title+%C2%A0+middle+%C2%A0+entry+%C2%A0+%C2%A0
```

`implode(', ', unpack('C*', $title))` returns:

```
84, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103, // Testing
32, // space
116, 105, 116, 108, 101, // title
32,
194, 160, // &nbsp;
32,
109, 105, 100, 100, 108, 101, // middle
32,
194, 160,
32,
101, 110, 116, 114, 121, // entry
32,
194, 160,
32,
194, 160
```

`$title` ultimately is just a `$_POST['title']`.

How do I trim all whitespaces from this string?

---

**FINALLY, THE SOLUTION WAS:**

```
$title = preg_replace('/\s/iu', ' ', $title)
```

Comment: does trimming it (with `$.trim`) client-side before sending work ?

Comment: Yes, client-side trimming works, but that doesn't change the fact that I want this to take place server-side. Also, [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418812/jquery-trim-doesnt-remove-nbsp) reveals, that there is a bug in IE (MSAjax) with the clientside `$.trim()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing all `&nbsp;` with spaces before you start trimming?

```
$text= str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text)
```

Or, if you want to remain unicode safe, you can use `mb_eregi_replace`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php

**EDIT - Second approach:**

According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13992998/486780)

> 194 160 is the UTF-8 encoding of a NO-BREAK SPACE codepoint (the same codepoint that HTML calls  ).
>
> So it's really not a space, even though it looks like one. (You'll see it won't word-wrap, for instance.) A regular expression match for \s would match it, but a plain comparison with a space won't.

Try using regexp to match for it as suggested above?

Comment: Tried, it doesn't find `&nbsp;` there. Please see in question how the string looks like when posted over, that's how PHP sees it I suppose, therefore no `&nbsp;`'s there.

Comment: How about the second approach?

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s/iu', ' ', $title)` did it, yes. Didn't work with `mb_ereg_*` though.